# python requests download trough download button on page

Tags: python, python-requests

So I am creating an application were you can download files trough a link. This webpage contains a download button and that needs to be pressed in order to start the download. This is the link where you can reference to: [link](https://steamworkshopdownloader.io/download/1843822064). My code:

```
link = input("enter link: ")
r = requests.get(link, allow_redirects=True)
```

how can I make requests or any other library click on the download button and save this file?

Comment: you're best using something like selenium for this mate

Comment: I have no experience with selenium so how would this go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using selenium:

**INSTALLATION**

*Skip this if you already have selenium installed.*

1. Install Selenium, type the following in your terminal: pip3 install selenium
2. Now you need a webdriver for Selenium. If you are wanting to use Chrome, firstly type "chrome://version/" in your browser and find the version you are using. Then go to this [link](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and download the appropriate webdriver for your browser. If you are using a different browser, like Firefox for example, just type selenium [your browser] webdriver.

   [Installation docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html)

**CODE**

Now for the code (following code is for Chrome, you would only need to change `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` if you are using a different webdriver):

```
from selenium import webdriver #importing webdriver

PATH = "C:/path/to/chromedriver" #webdriver location
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

link = input("Enter link: ")
driver.get(link) #going to URL

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/main/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span/button")\
.click() #clicking on the button
```

I used full xpath to locate the button, but you can use multiple things as seen in the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).